# Where do I get armor for Dogmeat in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Where do I pick up this awesome looking armor for Dogmeat in Fallout 4?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's Dog Armor. Sometimes attack dogs will have armor on them, which can be looted from the dog's corpse. There are multiple types. The dogs are usually found with Raiders.

In addition to the armor, Dogmeat is also wearing a [Dog Helmet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_helmet). I have yet to see a dog helmet in any of my playthroughs, so I think they're less common.

Neither the armor nor the helmet provide any damage reduction, but they do both have weight.

According to the Fallout Wiki page on [Dog Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_armor):

> South-East of Walden Pond you can find a small cave guarded by 3 Mongrels. Scattered across this cave you can find Dog armor, a Dog helmet and a Chain dog collar.

You can also find [Light Dog Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Light_dog_armor) and [Heavy Dog Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Heavy_dog_armor), but the wiki does not list a specific location for these.

Comment: "It doesn't actually provide any damage reduction." This makes me sad. Is this confirmed?

Comment: @JasonHeine I have some, and it doesn't provide any damage reduction. The wiki page agrees.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information. Time to browse the wiki. :)

Comment: What about the helmet?

Comment: The stats for the armour also show 0 and 0 for damage and energy resistance. It looks good though. I think I found it at the cave mentioned in the wiki, but didn't get the helmet, I'll have to go back and search again.

Comment: So much less useful than DD

Comment: @Timelord64 There's some extra info on the helmet. Not much to say.

Comment: Vouching for this answer: Got heavy armor and a helmet on Dogmeat right now. Pretty sure I pulled both off an attack dog. Also saw one recently with light armor. Hadn't noticed the lack of defenses though. After a sanity-check, I might just pull the armor off - he looks much better without it, IMO.